# how to capture all packet size using windows pktmon

Tags: windows, packet-capture

I am trying to use pktmon(built-in windows packet analyzer). However from the documentation they mention that by default packet size is limited to 128 bytes but can be increase with the following command `pktmon start --etw -p 0`.

But running that command gives me this error `Error: '0' is not a valid event provider Id`. what could be wrong?

So far I've not seen anything helpful on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the examples on the internet show

```
pktmon start --etw -p 0 -c 1
```

The -p doesn't seem to work and also the -c.
So what worked for me is

```
pktmon start --etw --pkt-size 0 --comp 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the utility help:

> --pkt-size 
> Number of bytes to log from each packet. To always log the entire
> packet set this to 0. Default is 128 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Add/Remove Filter:

```
pktmon filter remove # Remove All Filters
pktmon filter list   # List all Filters
pktmon filter add -I 100.100.100.0/24 # Capture the traffic for Specified IP
pktmon filter add -p 53 -I 100.100.100.0/16 101.101.101.0/16 # filter IP and Port
```

Start Realtime Capture:

```
pktmon start -c --comp nics -m real-time # Capture Real time
```

Stop Capture or Control C:

```
pktmon stop
```

Convert etl to pcap for wireshark:

```
mkdir C:\Temp1 # Create Directory where you want to store pcap
pktmon etl2pcap C:\WINDOWS\system32\PktMon.etl -o C:\Temp1\log.pcapng #  Convert etltp log.pcapng for wireshark
```

Answer (score 0):

> -p stands for provider which could be one/many of the following:

- Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP
- Microsoft-Windows-WINNAT
- [Microsoft-Windows-NDIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-analyzer/microsoft-windows-ndis-packetcapture-provider)

so example call utilizing 2 providers will be:

```
pktmon start --trace -p Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP -p Microsoft-Windows-NDIS -m real-time
```

help can give you some examples:

```
pktmon start help
```